# Java : how to get the expression through the jcombo list

Tags: java, swing

How do i create the one line expression using Java swing, link image  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ReLd.jpg). the every minute, every day,every month, every weekday and every hour need to convert it to "*" and also all the combo box contain the list of number [list number link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0dta.jpg) and weekday contain the  [click the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAIkd.jpg)

what i want is, if the user select "Every Minute" , "Every day","month = 2", "Weekday = monday", "hour= 3"

note of weekday JCombo : sunday = 0 , monday = 1, tuesday = 2 .....

the output will print as : * * 2 1 3

thanks alot.

i already tried this , my beginning code but cant do much :

```
String sjcb_EM = jcb_EM.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sjcb_EH = jcb_EH.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sjcb_ED = jcb_ED.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sjcb_EEM = jcb_EEM.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sjcb_EW = jcb_EW.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String vb_1 = sjcb_EM + " " + sjcb_EH + " " + sjcb_ED + " " + sjcb_EEM + " " + sjcb_EW;
```

System.out.println(vb_1);

now i stuck, how to make the expression that i wanted.

Comment: Instead of using `String`, create an object which provides a "display value" and a "query value", then use this as the object in the `JComboBox`, when you need to, "get the query value"

Comment: sorry dude, bit confuse.. can u provide me a link or example so that i can follow. thank you

Comment: You're working in an object orientated programming language, when ever you need to combine two or values, there's an opportunity for new a object to do the work. In this case, `JComboBox` can display any object through the use of a `ListCellRenderer` or, as I've done, by overriding the `toString` method

Answer (score 0):

Start by building a class which can hold both the display value and the query value...

```
public class WorkoutUnit {
    private String displayValue;
    private String queryValue;

    public WorkoutUnit(String displayValue, String queryValue) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
        this.queryValue = queryValue;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }

    public String getQueryValue() {
        return queryValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

Build a `ComboBoxModel` using these values...

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<WorkoutUnit> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
model.addElement(new WorkoutUnit("Every Minute", "*"));
for (int index = 10; index < 61; index += 10) {
    model.addElement(new WorkoutUnit(Integer.toString(index), Integer.toString(index)));
}
JComboBox<WorkoutUnit> cb = new JComboBox(model);
```

When needed, get the selected item from the combo box and get its query value...

```
WorkoutUnit unit = (WorkoutUnit)cb.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println("Query = " + unit.getQueryValue());
```

In this example, I've used `toString` to provide the display value to the `JComboBox`, this is not my preferred solution, I'd prefer to use a `ListCellRenderer` as demonstrated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Oh, and because it looks like you're heading down a database query route, you should also have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)